# Как поместить один div в другой div через jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

есть такая структура

<div id="header">......</div>

<div id="menu-bar>....</div>

Можно #menu-bar поместить в #header?

Answer (score 2):

Все до банального просто:

```
$('#header').prepend($('#menu-bar'));
```